# Is there a method to take the data from a file given as path to an API which is on remote server from a local system

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app service in a remote which accepts url and extracts data.
If i give the file path of my local system in the url, is there any way to read the path and tmp store the file on server and read the data?
I have tried directly reading the data from the api as url it does not work.

Comment: A remote service cannot read a local file from your filesystem. You need a client of some sort that reads the file and sends the content to the remote API (or you need to make the file accessible at a URL that the remote service can access).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.